# longtable OK but longtblr gives error on same exact content. why?

Tags: longtable, tabularray

I was trying `longtblr` and found it gives an error. `longtable` works ok on same input.

First time trying `longtblr`. Is there something one needs to do to make `longtblr` work on the same input?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arctanh}{arctanh}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}{|p{0.4in}|p{2in}|p{4in}|}\hline
\# & ODE & solution \\\hline
92&
A
&
{\small 
\begin{dmath*}
-\ln \left(\frac{y \left(x \right)}{x}\right)+\arctanh \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{y \left(x \right)^{2}}{x^{2}}+1}}\right)-\ln \left(x \right)-c_{1} = 0
\end{dmath*}
Verified OK. \verb|{0 < x}|
}\\ \hline
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

And now

```
>lualatex foo.tex
.....
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
}
l.46 \end
       {longtblr}
?
```

Compare to, same file, just changed  `longtblr` to `longtable` and now it compiles

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arctanh}{arctanh}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}    
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.4in}|p{2in}|p{4in}|}\hline
\# & ODE & solution \\\hline
92&
A
&
{\small 
\begin{dmath*}
-\ln \left(\frac{y \left(x \right)}{x}\right)+\arctanh \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{y \left(x \right)^{2}}{x^{2}}+1}}\right)-\ln \left(x \right)-c_{1} = 0
\end{dmath*}
Verified OK. \verb|{0 < x}|
}\\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

And now

```
>lualatex foo.tex
(./foo.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
Overfull \hbox (108.52753pt too wide) in alignment at lines 35--47
 [][][] 
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./foo.aux))
....
Output written on foo.pdf (1 page, 64594 bytes).
Transcript written on foo.log.
>
```

No problem.

TL 2022 on Linux.

Comment: because longtable is the best package ever?

Comment: `tabularray` does have  manual, see section 3.1.5 for how to use `\verb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

In common with any environment that grabs the environment body, you can't use `\verb` directly. `tblr` has a `verb` key that enables `\verb` but this is apparently not set up in the long version, so I used `\detokenize` here

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arctanh}{arctanh}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}


\begin{longtblr}{|p{0.4in}|p{2in}|p{4in}|}\hline
\# & ODE & solution \\\hline
92&
A
&
{\small 
\begin{dmath*}
-\ln \left(\frac{y \left(x \right)}{x}\right)+\arctanh \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{y \left(x \right)^{2}}{x^{2}}+1}}\right)-\ln \left(x \right)-c_{1} = 0
\end{dmath*}
Verified OK. \texttt{\detokenize{{0 < x}}}
}\\ \hline
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```